# Async constructor in Typescript

Tags: typescript, asynchronous

In one of my typescript file, I have 2 classes each with a constructor. Then inside each of the class, it needs to get an instance of the class of each other. I have the code as following:

```
namespace pxsim {
    export class Board extends pxsim.BaseBoard {
        public tMap: trafficMap = new trafficMap();
        public x: number;
        public y: number;
        constructor(){
            this.y = 10;
            this.x = this.tMap.x;
        }
    }
    export class trafficMap{
        public b: Board = new Board();
        public y: number;
        public x: number;
        constructor(){
            this.x = 20;
            this.y = this.b.y;
        }
    }
}
```

when I run it in browser, the console shows an error saying `"trafficMap is not a constructor"`. I think its because in `Board` class, when it tries to create an instance of `trafficMap`, as the code has not reached `trafficMap` class yet, it does not have loaded the content of it yet. Thus, I think I need something like async constructors. Please correct me if anything wrong.

Comment: If you don’t want to adopt the correct answer, you can do dependency injection with proxy.

Answer (score 0):

> Thus, I think I need something like async constructors. Please correct me if anything wrong.

There are no async constructors.

## Fix

When you have two classes that depend on each other, what you really have is Three classes. Two independent ones (which you already have) and one orchestrator (the true coupling between the two you have).

- Quickest fix: Just make one class that combines features of all three.
- Better: Seperate features into three classes as required.

Comment: Do I seperate features according to its functionality?

Comment: in my case, what if all the features in class `trafficMap` depends on the settings from `Board`, and the `Board` needs to get a instance of `trafficMap` to run the functions in `trafficMap` to do some thing?